# How do I map and filter distinct on an array with typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What is the proper way of mapping and filtering when trying to get distinct elements into another array?

I've tried several different ways but I keep getting an syntax error of "Illegal return statement".

My goal is to show distinct item from an array such as below. So if 'Level' = 'b' it would add it to the 'levelsList' array only once.

```
//small example of the data set returned from myService.myMethod() that I'm trying to filter on:
[
 {
    "ID": 1,
    "Level": "a",
    "Year": 1
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Level": "b",
    "Year": 2
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Level": "b",
    "Year": 2
  },
]


levelsList: string[] = [];

//returns syntax error on the 'level.Level'
         this.myService.myMethod().subscribe(
           data => {
             this.levelsList = data
               .filter((level) => {
                 return level.Level === this.usrInfo.a;
               }).map((level) => {
                 return level.Level;
               }).sort();
           });

 //returns syntax error at filter p.Level
         this.myService.myMethod().subscribe(
           data => {
             this.levelsList = data.map(p => p.Level).filter(p => p.Level === this.usrInfo.a).sort();
           });

 //returns syntax error
         this.myService.myMethod().subscribe(
           data => {
             this.levelsList = data.map((p) => p.Level)
               .filter((p) => p.level === this.usrInfo.a).sort();
           });
```

Comment: Can we see `myMethod()`?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: myMethod() just returns the data set. The error is "Illegal return statement".

Comment: Ok, this is confusing. So that array with 3 objects.. That is from the service?

Comment: this looks like a typing issue on your end.  The type returned by myMethod() doesn't match the interface you expect. but the second 2 have errors in any event, as once you map to the Level property, that string just is the item, so they don't have a Level property anymore.

Comment: @wentijun yes it's an example of the data from the service

Comment: @bryan60 I can get it to somewhat work with "this.levelsList = data.map((p) => p.Level).filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) === index).sort();"   but this gives me [a, b, c, d]  from a set like [a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c] and I'm just wanting [a] or [b] .. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello following my suggestion

```
        const levelselect = "a";

        this.result = this.json
               .filter((f) => {
                 return f.Level == levelselect
               })
               .map((level) => {
                 return level.Level;
               })
               .filter((value,index,self) => {
                 return self.indexOf(value) == index
               })
               .sort();
```

check for more example here https://codeburst.io/javascript-array-distinct-5edc93501dc4
also created a plunker to test https://next.plnkr.co/edit/bXWCDc4GjUITshgN?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Comment: this almost works. it's returning all distinct, but I need it to return distinct of specific level. For example I tried 'return level.Level === this.usrInfo.a;'  ... that throws an error.

Comment: Hi @ironman just updated the code, my suggestion to solve this is add another filter before the map, double check what kind info  you have info this object this.usrInfo.a, do like console.log(this.usrInfo.a) and check in your browser